# How to access ViewModel from attachBaseContext()?

Tags: android, mvvm, sharedpreferences, viewmodel, google-play-core

For each activity we want to use a language resource that an app has downloaded using Play Core Library, we need to update the base context and set a new locale through its *Configuration*:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
  val configuration = Configuration()
  configuration.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(sharedPrefs.getString(LANGUAGE_SELECTION)))
  val context = base.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
  super.attachBaseContext(context)
  SplitCompat.install(this)
}
```

As you can see, the language is retrieved from the *Shared Preferences*. However, using *MVVM*, where the *repository* pattern is responsible for dealing with the *Shared Preferences* and a *ViewModel* communicates with it, how to access that *ViewModel* from `attachBaseContext()`?

Trying to call the *ViewModel* from `attachBaseContext()` returns the following error: `You can’t request ViewModel before onCreate call`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get Activity's `ViewModel` from  `override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context)` method because, `Activity` keep a ViewModel objects in `ViewModelStore`(restore from it too). To get a ViewModelStore an Activity (AppCompatActivity) invoke the `ComponentActivity.getViewModelStore()`. Method `getViewModelStore()`
check value of `Activity.getApplication()`: if the value is null then you get an error like in your question:

```
"Your activity is not yet attached to the "
"Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call."
```

Method `Activity.getApplication()` return value of `Activity.mApplication` variable which will be initialed after the `attachBaseContext(base: Context)` had executed (from `attach method`). Actually, we need gain access to Activity's `NonConfigurationInstances` objet i.e. `Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. In this object an activity saves `ViewModelStore` around the configuration changing. `NonConfigurationInstances` object passes as argument of final Activity's method `attach`(we can't override them) from which the method `attachBaseContext(base: Context)`invoked but the object will be saved in activity after the `attachBaseContext` method had executed.

You can save your ViewModel in application but I think it hasn't sense(It's bad idea). How does MVVM or `MMVM`(from your answer) limiting using a repository directly ? Looks like it's a corner case :)